# how do i import file from app.js to components in react

Tags: reactjs, components

i have following file structure

.components
.coma

app.js

i have tried

```js
import myname form "./app.js"
```

and also

```js
import myname form ".//app.js" in compa
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-newton-ms3umk?file=/src/App.js)

There are two ways that you can export a function, component, etc:

1. Default exports:
   To export:

```
export default function Component() {
  return <div></div>;
}
```

To import

```
import Component from './Component';
```

2. Named exports:
   To export:

```
export function Component() {
  return <div>Component</div>;
}
```

To import

```
import { Component } from './Component';
```

[See this link](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-export-component-function#:%7E:text=Use%20named%20exports%20to%20export,as%20necessary%20in%20a%20file.) for more information about exporting components in React

**EDIT:**

You can declare your components and functions and export them in another line.